# What's the word for dropping buzzwords frequently?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm pretty sure there is a word for this, I remember seeing it on the Internet once and the closest I have is "buzzwording" (not a real word?)

Comment: Bullshitting...!

Comment: [Bullshit Bingo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword_bingo) comes to mind here. (As does *manager*.)

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a one a *jargonista.*

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jargonista

Answer (score 0):

On the grounds that many such people may be using an [Oval Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval_Books) guide,...

> [**bluffer**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/bluffer)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a [project manager](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Project%20Manager).  Definitely at my company.

> Somone who uses endless buzz words and centres their existance around
>   a load of paperwork, meetings, conference calls and turning every
>   task, no matter how small, into an epic display of verbal and written
>   diarrhea. Jobs that once needed a sensible tradeperson or two, now
>   need to be a project with a project manager. They sit between the
>   workers and management and are very good at being on the side of
>   whoever they are talking to and ensuring that they are never in the
>   same room as both workers and management. Commanding huge amounts of
>   money, they are gifted in prolonging everything.

Comment: In order to be certified by the PMI you need to be able to spout specific jargon as defined by the PMBOK® (Project Management Body of Knowledge). If it costs a lot it shouldn't be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [sophomoric](http://ninjawords.com/?q=sophomoric) because buzzwords are relatively new words that are not well-established. So being too quick to adopt them might be a sign that someone is a `follower`, `sheep`, or `sophomoric`.

In another sense, someone who is in `Marketing` will use buzzwords frequently by the nature of their job.